# Solution for jetpack compose column lagging issue

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Scrolling is lagging using Jetpack compose column,

```
 Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
  View()
  View()
  View()
  ...
  }
```

This is sample example but I am facing issue if lagging while scrolling on real devices

Answer (score 4):

You should use `LazyColumn` in case when you need to display a list of many views.

Here is [playground](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/foundation/lazycolumn/) of this component.

Also, note that the performance in a `debug` build is very different from the performance you will have in a `release` build with `isDebuggable = false`

If you run into performance issues despite using a `LazyColumn` on a release build, here's a great optimization [article](https://chrisbanes.me/posts/composable-metrics/#exploring-the-metrics).